# A predicate that takes a list and repeats each element X amount of times - Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I can get the result to be true, but when I attempt to make it false I feel like it is in an endless loop.

```
repeat(L,N,Result):-
    rHelp(L,N,[],Result).

rHelp(_,_,Result,Result).
rHelp([H|T],N,L1,L2):-
    dupe(H,N,[],L3),
    append(L1,L3,L4),
    rHelp(T,N,L4,L2).

dupe(_,0,L,L).
dupe(H,N,L,Result):-
    N1 is N-1,
    append(L,[H],L1),
    dupe(H,N1,L1,Result).
```

Example Test:

```
repeat( [a, b, c], 2, [a, a, b, b, c, c] )
repeat( [1, a, 2, b], 0, [ ] )
repeat( [1, 1, 2], 3, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] )
```

which are all True. I am just trying to get a false result.

Answer (score 0):

One reason it's hard to make your program fail is that it describes too many incorrect solutions:

```
?- repeat([a, b, c], 2, Result).
Result = [] ;
Result = [a, a] ;
Result = [a, a, b, b] ;
Result = [a, a, b, b, c, c] ;
% nontermination
```

The reason you accept too many solutions is the first clause of `rHelp/4`:

```
rHelp(_,_,Result,Result).
```

Here you say that for *any* input list, at any point in the computation where you have an intermediate result `Result`, that is a correct solution. But this is not the case. The intermediate result is only a complete result once you have exhausted the entire input list. This clause should be:

```
rHelp([], N, Result, Result).
```

Note that I found this essentially by pattern matching. Adjacent clause heads like

```
foo(_, Bar).
foo([H|T], Bar) :- ...
```

simply *look* incorrect. Why is the `_` not an empty list? In *most* cases a predicate like this would have mutually exclusive patterns in the head, and here that is not the case.

With this fixed, we can try the test again:

```
?- repeat([a, b, c], 2, Result).
Result = [a, a, b, b, c, c] ;
% nontermination
```

Better! But it still goes searching for more solutions although there are none. This, too, is a case of clauses not being mutually exclusive:

```
dupe(_,0,L,L).
dupe(H,N,L,Result):-
    N1 is N-1,
    ...
```

If the second argument is not `0`, the second clause applies. If the second argument is `0`, the first clause applies... but so does the second! After finding a solution using the first clause, Prolog will backtrack and execute the second clause with `N = 0`. Then `N1` will become `-1`, and your program goes off recursively looking for negative infinity.

The fix is to add a guard `N > 0` in the second clause. And with these two changes, the test works as desired:

```
?- repeat([a, b, c], 2, Result).
Result = [a, a, b, b, c, c] ;
false.
```

One general point to observe here is that it was easier to understand the behavior of your predicate by using less specific queries. There is no need to specify a fixed list for the `Result` argument: Leave it free and see what Prolog gives you!